# on loading fieldset how can i focus to my selected textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, textfield, fieldset

I have more than one `fieldset` in my page. Each has few number of `textfield` in it.

I want to focus any selected `textfield`. How can i do this?

suppose if i have like this

```
<fieldset>
<legend>First Page</legend>
<input id="bp1" name="bp1" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="bp2" name="bp2" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="bp3" name="bp3" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend> Next Page</legend>
<input id="other1" name="other1" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="other2" name="other2" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="other3" name="other3" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />

</fieldset>
<div id="navigation" style="display:none;">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="selected">
                            <a href="#">First Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Next Page</a>
                        </li>
```

I want to focus on my 3rd textfield(id="bp3") in first page and in the next page i want to focus to 2nd textfield i.e id="other3". How to do this?

Comment: You can only focus one element in the document at any given time ?

Comment: yes i want to focus only one of the selected textfield and not the first one

Answer (score 0):

use [focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the field you want to focus like

`document.getElementById('bp3').focus()`

then on next page `visibility` event i.e. onclick of next page

`<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('other3').focus()">Next Page</a>`

Comment: thanks. I want to know in which event should i call this script? I want to execute the script on loading of fieldset

Comment: insanity - you can call this script onload event of your body or on document.readyState check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.readyState

Comment: If i put it onlaod of my body then the focus will work only once. I want onloading of each fieldset so that my selected textfield will focus

Comment: then place the code where the fieldset loading takes place.
or share code how you load the fieldset to help you.

Comment: my code is very lengthy so i edited my question with a similar code in shorter way

Comment: how can i use visibility event and how to write it on fieldset ? please help me i did it using onload but it didnt work

Comment: how do you go to next page?

Comment: I have a div at the end through which i navigate to my fieldset using jquery plugin

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41115/discussion-between-insanity-and-niksvp)